# Allocating two Layout/TableRow Dynamically in One Activity

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablerow

**Problem in Allocating two Layout Dynamically in One Activity**

i am trying to work on a logic in which i need to allocate two LinearLayout or TableRow in two Horizontal Scroll view in same Activity Layout but it does'nt seem to be working. any help will be appreciated

this
is
code
here of activity:

```
public class ViewTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout LinearLayoutInScrollView;
    LinearLayout Inner1HorizontalLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout Inner2HorizontalLinearLayout;
    ScrollView ScrollViewMain;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollViewOfMain;
    TextView textViewOne;
    TextView textViewTwo;
    Button verticalScrollTriggerButton;
    Button horizontalScrollTriggerButton;

    @Override    

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            LinearLayoutInScrollView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainscrollViewLayout);

            horizontalScrollViewOfMain = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
            LinearLayoutInScrollView.addView(horizontalScrollViewOfMain);



            verticalScrollTriggerButton = new Button(this);
            verticalScrollTriggerButton.setText("CheckVerticalScroll");
            verticalScrollTriggerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        textViewOne = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        textViewOne.setBackgroundColor(0xaa000000);
                        textViewOne.setText("This is Dynamic");
                        LinearLayoutInScrollView.addView(textViewOne);
                    }

                }
            });

            horizontalScrollTriggerButton = new Button(this);
            horizontalScrollTriggerButton.setText("CheckHorizontalScroll");
            horizontalScrollTriggerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Inner1HorizontalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                    Inner2HorizontalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());               
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        textViewOne = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        textViewOne.setBackgroundColor(0xaa000000);
                        textViewOne.setText("This is Dynamic textViewOne");
                        Inner1HorizontalLinearLayout.addView(textViewOne);
                        textViewTwo = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        textViewTwo.setBackgroundColor(0xaa000000);
                        textViewTwo.setText("This is Dynamic textViewTwo");
                        Inner2HorizontalLinearLayout.addView(textViewTwo);                  
                    }
                    horizontalScrollViewOfMain.addView(Inner1HorizontalLinearLayout);
                    horizontalScrollViewOfMain.addView(Inner2HorizontalLinearLayout);
                }

            });

            LinearLayoutInScrollView.addView(verticalScrollTriggerButton);
            LinearLayoutInScrollView.addView(horizontalScrollTriggerButton);

        }
```

this
is
code
here of main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/MainscrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/MainscrollViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first issue I see are these 2 lines:

```
horizontalScrollViewOfMain.addView(Inner1HorizontalLinearLayout);
horizontalScrollViewOfMain.addView(Inner2HorizontalLinearLayout);
```

Any scrollView is a frame view, and can only have one internal view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

I am not at a computer right now to run code/look at more detail, and you didn't give much detail as to what the exact issue your having. But see if that fixed your problem.

Comment: first of all thank you soo much for considering the problem. i was thinking it will go unnoticed. gonna check the solution though my problem is that when i initialize two layout Or Two TableRow consecutively the second one comes out as null.

Comment: Solved.. thank you :)... though now another problem has popped up.

Comment: No problem, Glad I could help. If your problem is very similar to the one you had in your question, tell me what it is and I can try to help. But if its a little different you might want to make an entirely new question. Make sure to hit the check mark next to my answer so the question is marked solved (if you make a new question).

Comment: no.. its a bit different problem. i'll try to figure it out :) thank you again :).. marked it as solved :)